# NSLayout Constraint not working on Custom View

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I am creating a custom UIView in swift, here is the code for the custom View,

```
class FormField: UIView {
    
    @IBOutlet var viewLabel : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var separator: UIView!
    
    private var verticallyCenteredAnchor : NSLayoutConstraint!
    private var topPositionedAnchor : NSLayoutConstraint!
    private var isViewHighlighted = false
    private var view: UIView?
    
    let nibName = "FormField"

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    override class var requiresConstraintBasedLayout: Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func commonInit() {
        guard let view = loadViewFromNib() else { return }
        self.view = view
        view.frame = self.bounds
        self.addSubview(view)
        
        
        verticallyCenteredAnchor =  viewLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view!.centerYAnchor)
        verticallyCenteredAnchor.isActive = false
        topPositionedAnchor = viewLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view!.topAnchor,constant: 0)
        topPositionedAnchor.isActive = true
        
        let userNameTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(animateLabel))
        userNameTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        view.addGestureRecognizer(userNameTap)
    }
    
    @objc func animateLabel() {
        if(self.isViewHighlighted) {
            verticallyCenteredAnchor.isActive = true
            topPositionedAnchor.isActive = false
        } else {
            verticallyCenteredAnchor.isActive = false
            topPositionedAnchor.isActive = true

        }
        self.isViewHighlighted = !self.isViewHighlighted
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.view!.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
    
    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView? {
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: nil)
        return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView
        }
}
```

I am using a xib file for the view and constraints are set in that. Now when someone taps on the view I am trying to change the constraints with animation. But that's not working, no layout change is happening when the user taps on the view. I can confirm that the animateLabel() method is called when the user taps.

Now if is add in the line,

```
self.view!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

all constraints are messed up, it's not honouring the constraints I already set in the xib.

What's going wrong here?

Comment: If you are setting constraints on `viewLabel` in you XIB, your code is ***adding*** more constraints, but that doesn't ***remove*** the existing constraints. Create `@IBOutlet` connections from your XIB and modify their `.priority` or `.isActive` properties in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I am using a xib file for the view and constraints are set in that.**

You have conflicts in your constraints who are in xib + in code , you need to hook the constraints in xib as outlets and play with their `.isActive` property and completely remove the code constraints